# Find equation for a hyperbola without asymptote

Tags: conic-sections

[image: equation for a hyperbola without asymptote]

I have a hyperbola graph with points (3,4) and (8,3). The graph can be modelled using

y = a / ( x - b)

I need to write the equation when x = 3 and find the values of a and b.

I don't know how to get a and b without knowing the asymptotes. Please advise how I can calculate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert the given points into the equation, obtain 2 equations in 2 variables and solve for those, i.e. for a and b.

--- rk

Comment: Ugh, of course. Thanks